# Angularjs and twitter bootstrap - creating X items per row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using `angular.js` with `twitter bootstrap` to create client-side of an web-application.

I am wondering, what is the proper way to do something like this

[image]

For now I am doing something like this

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3" ng-repeat="set in selectedCollection.sets">
            {{set.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code, even if I have for example 4 elements, I get 2 rows, first one with 3 elements, second one with one element. Event if this solution works (for now) I am wondering about this:

```
To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .span* columns within an existing .span* column. Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to the number of columns of its parent.
```

this part is from official bootstrap documentation.

If this is an improper way to do this kind of thing, how can it be achieved? Should I somehow split this data to 2 dimensional array and create two nested loops so I will have 3 `span3` divs in every row?

If that is the case, I would create a function in model that would return this two dimensional array based on one dimensional array and use `ng-repeat="dimensionalSet in mappingFunction()"` in my outer element.

Comment: nesting infers taking one of your `span3` and putting a `row` inside it and then using `span3` to split that inner row in 3 as example. Not sure what your issue really is...although it appears to be misinterpretation of docs. Provide a real html demo in jsfiddle.net if problem is more advanced than the simple rows shown in image

Comment: Here is the thing I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/VX5LE/21/. When you click `+` button you are adding one `span3` element to the nested row in `span9`. In my browser and at my resolution I am getting what I want: 3 elements per "row", but I am breaking the rule that `Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to the number of columns of its parent.`

Answer (score 0):

I was actually thinking of this situation also.
I don't think your fiddle is wrong. It shouldn't be a problem if those nested row columns don't add up to the parent number of columns.

One thing you could do is do the ng-repeat over a collection of objects where each object contained an array of three objects, then always add those three objects even if some of them are empty. If you are getting the results from a service call, you can do this on the server side before sending the results back.